# How to initialize a struct in C

Tags: c

Since 2-3 days I have a small problem with a project, in fact my project is to make a roundabout with cars. I am beginner in C so I tried to initialize a struct by myself.

My struct is :

```
typedef struct Car Car;
struct Car
{
char vehicule; /* N, S, E, W */
int speed; /* 1 => slow ou 2 => fast */
int pos_i; /* Position courante 'i' du véhicule sur la route */
int pos_j; /* Position courante 'j' du véhicule sur la route */
char alig; /* 'l' for left and 'r' for right */
};
```

Then I create a function called initCar, in order to put two random cars at (23,1) at the red circle, (21,1) the orange one, like this :

My initCar function:

```
Car initCar () {

    Car car [43][90] = {{0}};
    char direction [] = {'N', 'S', 'E', 'W'};

    int position [2][2] = {{0}}; 
    position [0][0] = 23;
    position [0][1] = 1;
    position [1][0] = 21;
    position [1][1] = 1;

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    srand (time (NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 43; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 90; j++) {
            car [i][j].vehicule = direction [rand () % 4];
            car [i][j].speed = 1;
            car [i][j].pos_i = position [i][j];
            car [i][j].pos_j = position [i][j];
            car [i][j].alignement = 'r';
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
    roadMap(car); 
}
```

But I have this when I execute:

[image: The problem]

roadMap is my roundabout function,

```
else if (j < 33) {
   do {
        printf("%c", matrice[i][j].vehicule);
        j++;
   } while (j < 33);
}
```

Based on : [image]

(my mcve)

function.h :

```
#ifndef FONCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FONCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NB_LIN 43
#define NB_COL 90

#define clrscr() printf("\033[H\033[2J")
#define couleur(param) printf("\033[%sm",param)

typedef struct Car Car;
struct Car
{
char vehicule; /* N, S, E, W */
int speed; /* 1 => slow ou 2 => fast */
int pos_i; /* Position courante 'i' du véhicule sur la route */
int pos_j; /* Position courante 'j' du véhicule sur la route */
char alig; /* 'l' for left and 'r' for right */
}; 

void roadMap (char matrice [NB_LIN][NB_COL]);
void initCarFromEst ();
```

main.c :

```
#include "function.h"

int main () {

    initCarFromEst ();

    return 0;
}
```

And function.c :

```
void myDelay (float i) { // Fais une pause de l'app durant i secondes

    clock_t start, end;

    start = clock ();
    while (((end = clock ()) - start) <= i * CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

void roadMap (Car matrice [NB_LIN][NB_COL]) {


    int i = 0, j = 0;

    //NB_LIN de NB_COL
    for (i = 0; i < NB_LIN; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NB_COL; j++) {

            switch (i) {
                case 20: {
                    if (j < 19) {
                        do {
                            printf("■");
                            j++;
                        } while (j < 19);
                    }
                    else if (j < 33) {
                        do {
                            printf("%c", matrice[i][j].vehicule);
                            j++;
                        } while (j < 33);
                    }
                    else if (j < 53) {
                        do {
                            printf("╬");
                            j++;
                        } while (j < 53);
                    }
                    else if (j < 67) {
                        do {
                            printf("%c", matrice[i][j].vehicule);
                            j++;
                        } while (j < 67);
                    }
                    else if (j < 87) {
                        do {
                            printf("■");
                            j++;
                        } while (j < 87);
                    }
                }
                break;

                case 18: 
                case 22: {
                    if (j < 10) {
                        do {
                            printf("─ ");
                            j++;
                        } while (j < 10);
                    }
                    else if (j < 23) {
                        do {
                            printf("%c", matrice[i][j].vehicule);
                            j++;
                        } while (j < 23);
                    }
                    else if (j < 43) {
                        do {
                            printf("╬");
                            j++;
                        } while (j < 43);
                    }
                    else if (j < 57) {
                        do {
                            printf("%c", matrice[i][j].vehicule);
                            j++;
                        } while (j < 57);
                    }
                    else if (j < 68) {
                        do {
                            printf("─ ");
                            j++;
                        } while (j < 68);
                    }
                }
                break;
} printf("\n");
}
}

Car initCarFromWest () {

    Car car [43][90] = {{0}};
    char direction [] = {'N', 'S', 'E', 'W'};

    int position [2][2] = {{0}}; 
    position [0][0] = 23;
    position [0][1] = 1;
    position [1][0] = 21;
    position [1][1] = 1;

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    srand (time (NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 43; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 90; j++) {
            car [i][j].vehicule = direction [rand () % 4];
            car [i][j].speed = 1;
            car [i][j].pos_i = position [i][j];
            car [i][j].pos_j = position [i][j];
            car [i][j].alignement = 'r';
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
    roadMap(car); 
}

Voiture initCarFromEst () {

}

Voiture initCarFromSouth () {

}

Voiture initCarFromNorth () {

}
```

My function roadMap is nearly 400 lines that's why i gave you a sample

Comment: If you only want to place two cars, why do you create 3870 cars?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Click the blue link in @Guillaume's comment :) It's short for *Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example* – that way we can reproduce your problem case to test out possible solutions. As it is, we need to invent a framework around your code just to run it, and this may hide your error.

Comment: I put my mcve in the answers

Comment: Jongware i made the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you're not creating 2 cars, you're creating 43*90 = 3870 cars.  You are declaring a 43x90 array of cars, for a total of 3870 cars.  You then iterate over all of the cars in the array, initializing all 3870 of them.  But you're indexing outside of the bounds of your `position` array.  `position` is a 2x2 array, so both indices must be in the range [0,1].  But you're using your loop indices to index into it, so you are going way past the bounds of the array, and you're getting whatever values happen to be on the call stack.

It sounds like what you want to do just have 2 cars.  That should work a lot better.

Comment: At the end of my project i have to make a program who can move my cars like this ;

[Moving Cars][1]

That's why i made a 2d Array with 43 lin and 90 col


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pzkY4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have 43*90 cars, as you just declared `Car car[43][90]`.
Even if you declared them as 'empty' (containing 0).

I suggest you modify your code as following: `Car* car[43][90] = {{0}};` and basically have every pointer set as `NULL` and the non empty ones pointing to a dynamically allocated car (moving it would also be more efficient, aside from the obvious minimization in memory consumption. Of course you'll need to modify your map drawing function accordingly.

Your `position[i][j]` is wrong as both `i` and `j` travel outside of the array limits (position is only `[2][2]`). I suppose that your map is 43x90 and that's where your confusion came from. If this is the case, you shouldn't even have a position variable (`pos_i` and `pos_j`) as the array index already marks the position (say `arr[i][j]` is the car, then the car is in `i, j`).

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying (i am so bad in english) ^^ do you have any examples ?